# Npgsql Error With Column

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have a Model  and have the same database table. Both are synchronized. I have another database at some other server and I am ussing the same model for it but different dbContext.

My system what it does it check in the local dbcontext and fetch some rows then it checks the same row with unique id. But when it Adds the row in the table it gives me the error 
of

```
ERROR: 42703: column "etrue" does not exist
```

I dont know what is wrong my table has the same columns as declared in the Model

here is my model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CacsSynchronizer.Models
{
    public class Cards
    {
        [Key]
        public string ecode { get; set; }
        public string ename { get; set; }
        public string designation { get; set; }
        public string department { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> modifidedate { get; set; }
        public string fname { get; set; }
        public string address1 { get; set; }
        public string address2 { get; set; }
        public string address3 { get; set; }
        public string telres { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> birth { get; set; }
        public string division { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> timingin { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> timingout { get; set; }
        public string jemail { get; set; }
        public string altemail { get; set; }
        public string mobile_no { get; set; }
        public string vehicle { get; set; }
        public string company { get; set; }
        public byte[] tpl { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> registered { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> validity { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string serial { get; set; }
        public byte[] photo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> manual { get; set; }
        public string visit_to { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> deo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> employee { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> active { get; set; }
        public string printing { get; set; }
        public string modifideby { get; set; }
        public string container { get; set; }
        public string gate1 { get; set; }
        public string gate2 { get; set; }
        public string gate3 { get; set; }
        public string gate4 { get; set; }
        public string gate5 { get; set; }
        public string gate6 { get; set; }
        public string gate7 { get; set; }
        public string level { get; set; }
        public string containerout { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> psf_staff { get; set; }
        public string gateno { get; set; }
        public string gate_in { get; set; }
        public string gate_out { get; set; }
        public string visit_name { get; set; }
        public string gate8 { get; set; }
        public string gate9 { get; set; }
        public string gate10 { get; set; }
        public string gate11 { get; set; }
        public string gate12 { get; set; }
        public string gate13 { get; set; }
        public string gate14 { get; set; }
        public string gate15 { get; set; }
        public string own_nic { get; set; }
        public string gate16 { get; set; }
        public string gate17 { get; set; }
        public string gate18 { get; set; }
        public string gate19 { get; set; }
        public string gate20 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

here is my code to manipulate

```
 public bool SyncLocalToCentralCards()
        {
            using (CacsLocalContext CacsLocalEnt = new CacsLocalContext())
            {
                IList<Cards> CardsData = CacsLocalEnt.Cards.SqlQuery("Select * From cards where ecode='3110305101335'").ToList();

                if(CardsData != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= CardsData.Count;i++ )
                    {
                        string ecode = CardsData[i].ecode;

                        using (CacsCentralContext CacsCentral = new CacsCentralContext())
                        {
                            IList<Cards> CentralCards = (from cards in CacsCentral.Cards
                                                where cards.ecode.Equals(ecode)
                                                  select cards).ToList();
                            if (CentralCards.Count != 0)
                            {

                                return true;
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                CacsCentral.Cards.Add(CardsData[i]);
                                try
                                {
                                    CacsCentral.SaveChanges();
                                    Components.MainWindowComponents.SyncUpdateCount(1);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    Components.MainWindowComponents.StatusUpdate(ex.Message);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                return false;
                }

            }

        }
```

Error in the Insert Statement Generated by Entity Framework

```
INSERT INTO "public"."cards"("ecode","ename","designation","department","modifidedate","fname","address1","address2","address3","telres","birth","division","timingin","timingout","jemail","altemail","mobile_no","vehicle","company","tpl","registered","validity","type","serial","photo","manual","visit_to","deo","employee","active","printing","modifideby","container","gate1","gate2","gate3","gate4","gate5","gate6","gate7","level","containerout","psf_staff","gateno","gate_in","gate_out","visit_name","gate8","gate9","gate10","gate11","gate12","gate13","gate14","gate15","own_nic","gate16","gate17","gate18","gate19","gate20") VALUES (E'3110305101335',E'M WAHEED',E'DR',NULL,NULL,E'M SADIQ',E'DIS. BAHAWAL NIGAR',E'',E'',NULL,TIMESTAMP '1989-08-27T00:00:00.0000000',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,E'TLA862',E'ZATRANSPORT TR',decode('pw==', 'base64'),TIMESTAMP '2013-03-05T22:56:36.0000000',TIMESTAMP '2013-03-06T22:56:36.0000000',E'CL',E'6050313822',decode('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', 'base64'),ETRUE,E'58',NULL,NULL,NULL,E'0',E'asifjbl',NULL,E'NO',E'NO',E'NO',E'NO',E'NO',E'NO',E'NO',E'1',NULL,NULL,E'6',E'',E'',E'Wiltrans Cargo Services',E'NO',E'NO',E'NO',E'NO',E'NO',E'NO',E'NO',E'NO',NULL,E'NO',E'NO',E'NO',E'NO',E'NO');
```

I dont know why it is put E in the column values

Comment: First, I don't see an "etrue" attribute in your model class, so it's unclear why your code would be generating queries to make use of it. Second, that error is from the database - the column doesn't exist in one (or both) of the tables. If the model in the code is supposed to use that column, then it needs to be added to the database.

Comment: thanx for your reply. well there is no such column in both of the tables i dont get it what seems to be the problem ..

Comment: The database error should come with the query that generated the error. If your client isn't showing you that query you can open up the database logs and check there.

Comment: ok i will check the logs

Comment: User re-posted as http://stackoverflow.com/q/20651886/398670

Comment: @ShakoorAlam The advice you got is good. **Look at the server logs** to see what query was run, and the full error message. Also figure out where in your code `etrue` appears; it isn't in the listing above. Make sure you're connecting to the same server you think you are, and that both are running the same version of the schema.

Comment: Yes I am connecting to the same server with two databases for development enviroment and both are running on the same version that is public schema

Comment: where are the server logs saved in postgreSql

Comment: @ShakoorAlam Sure it's really the same? Query `information_schema` via your Entity Framework connection to each, and compare the column lists. `select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'mytablename' and table_schema = 'public';`

Comment: @ShakoorAlam Did you look up where the server logs are saved before asking? -> google.

Comment: found the log ... should i post the Insert Query error in the post ?

Comment: Please check its putting E before every column value ..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43413/discussion-between-craig-ringer-and-shakoor-alam)

Comment: @ShakoorAlam The `E'value'` stuff is unrelated. It's the escape-string syntax. See the PostgreSQL user manual (lexical structure section) for information on escape-strings. They are not related to your problem.

Comment: I just got it fixed .... the problem is with the npgsql VisitedExpression.cs file which was compiled and had a bug with it while fetching the primitive datatype and putting the Boolean switch case with the String Switch case which was appending the escape-string Append('E') so i changed it compiled it... and it works now Thanks to all here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Npgsql [introduced in commit 864c4e9](https://github.com/magnitudo/Npgsql2/commit/864c2e937dffb8e0159a417edb42324677c1d05b) and [fixed in commit b07ae85 on July 5, 2013](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/commit/b07ae852566a4ff62d005e1dbff60ceccda597b8).

It looks like version 2.0.14.3 and later contains this fix. Updating the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/) will get the update, or you can get the binaries from their [releases page](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/releases).

Comment: Can you please provide me the link to lates npgsql dll

Comment: after updating the package i am getting this error The instance member of the entity framework provider type Npgsql.NpgsqlServices did not return an object that inherits  from base class...

Comment: It looks like I was wrong, the latest version doesn't contain the fix. You'll need to build from source.

Comment: can you please tell me the correct source so that I can build it... I am new to this PostgreSql

Comment: I cannot, I know nothing about Npgsql. I was able to find this answer by simply searching Google for "npgsql etrue"; the first hit described your exact problem.

Comment: However, most open source projects have a README file or other file in the root of the repository that tells you how to build them. I suggest you spend some time investigating that.